# Show data from mysql as css class

Tags: php, html, css

I have a column in my database called "reserved". Inside each row there may be a text also named "reserved" or it may be blank. My question is how can I show that text using PHP if it exists in the database? Meanwhile, I need the action of "echo" to be run separately from the PHP code and among the HTML codes. I would be grateful if you could correct my code.

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');

mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES utf8");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $reserved           = $row['reserved'];

    }
}
 
?>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td class="<?=$row['reserved']?>"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're assigning to variable `$reserved`, why use `$row->reserved` to output, where does this come from? Your `class` attribute and `<td>` are not closed. `$reserved` will be overwritten on each iteration, last one wins

Comment: Store your values in an array, then access the array values where you need them

Comment: If you have more than one result then your code will not work as you hope. The HTML table should be dynamically generated based upon the results from the db query - so rather than have the `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` before the actual HTML place that within the table to generate a new row per result